# How do I add Numba to the code to speed up the process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, jit, numba

Do I want to speed up my script processing with [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)? I know very little about Python and how to do it to make the script work faster.
This code adds two points using the [ECPy](https://github.com/cslashm/ECPy) module. Help me add to the code a [Numba](http://numba.pydata.org/) to speed up the process as a result?

```
from ecpy.curves import Curve, Point

cv = Curve.get_curve ('secp256k1')

P = Point (0x9a1ebff0a96c374ef74dff00542875c73430c3dbba0b0d81ed234a4996cd505f,
           0xd73b0c8e8feb26e0a57090919cc06fa36da4f07ea7911d9f2d23332401a7a715,
           cv)

W = Point (0x79be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798,
           0x483ada7726a3c4655da4fbfc0e1108a8fd17b448a68554199c47d08ffb10d4b8,
           cv)

R = P + W

print (R)
```

Comment: I doubt you can do much here. You can't usually apply Numba (or any other Python accelerator) on external code that you're using as a library. All the time is likely to be in the `ecpy` module and there's little you can do without starting to modify that module.

Answer (score -1):

For that script I think you'd have to edit the source to add Numba decorators to the relevant functions. [Here](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/index.html)'re the docs for Numba.

Comment: Sorry for my insistence, but can you help me fix the code? The fact is that I do not know the Python language well.